# How to make this code more efficient in python and in less time?

Tags: python, cycle

I have have an homework where I have to decode and codify a string of number using the Romanian alphabet.
1000
500
100
50
10
5
1

In this function I have a string like '10010010010100511'  called xkcd and I have to return an int list like [100, 100, 100, 10, 100, 5, 1, 1,] where I separate the numbers.
I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do this.
thanks

```
lista=[]

    for i in range(len(xkcd)):       #xkcd is a string given to the function

        if xkcd[i:i+4] == '1000':
          lista.append( int( xkcd[i:i+4] ) )

        elif xkcd[i:i+3] == '500':
            lista.append( int( xkcd[i:i+3] ) )
    
        elif xkcd[i:i+3] == '100':
            lista.append( int( xkcd[i:i+3] ) )

        elif xkcd[i:i+2] == '50':
            lista.append( int( xkcd[i:i+2] ) )

        elif xkcd[i:i+2] == '10':
            lista.append( int( xkcd[i:i+2] ) )

        elif xkcd[i:i+1] == '5':
            lista.append( int( xkcd[i:i+1] ) )

        elif xkcd[i:i+1] == '1':
          lista.append( int( xkcd[i:i+1] ) )

    return lista
```

Comment: This code is wasteful because, after you match 1000, you'll still check the next three digits, when you've already consumed them.  Are you REALLY given "10010010010100511", or are you given `CCCXCVII`?  THAT'S what Roman numerals are.

Comment: no, the input strings are like "10010010010100511"

Comment: and I can't use other libraries, so I can't use re.findall

Comment: Romanians don’t have a full alphabet of their own, they use the Latin alphabet (with diacritics).

Comment: @user3840170  I would say they have their own alphabet (an ordered(?) collection of characters) based on (like many Western alphabets) the Latin *script*.

Comment: In any case, the question appears to be about Roman numerals, not the Romanian alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

The best plan is to notice that zeros are the key.  If the character is not a 0, then it starts a new value.  If it is a zero, then it tacks on to the previous value.  This code looks at each character exactly once:

```
def analyze(xkcd):
    result = []
    for c in xkcd:
        if c == '0':
            result[-1] += c
        else:
            result.append( c )

    return result

print(analyze('10010010010100511'))
```

Output:

```
['100', '100', '100', '10', '100', '5', '1', '1']
```